# Push data in array in specific case

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am trying to push data in array with in specific indice.

At first, I have an empty array: `[]`

After receiving data from web socket (number), example number = 4, I want to push this number into the Array at position 4.

Output: `[null,null,null,null,4]`

Or I can't put anything else than null like : "-"

New output: `[-,-,-,-,4]`

After receiving second data from web socket, example number = 2.

New output: `[-,-,2,-,4]`

I tried this:

```js
let tArray = [];
for(let i=0; i<number + 1; i++){
   if(i == number){
      tArray[i].push(number);
   }
   if(!tArray[i]){
      tArray[i].push("-");
   }
}
```

Comment: `tArray` should be declared with const let or var

Comment: Also, you shouldn't push to a specific location, as you're not dealing with a 2-dimensional array

Comment: i try to push in specific location but output in every time i push : [ ] null. @MauriceNino

Comment: `push()` is meant to add a value to the end of an array. `tArray[i]` is not an array, so you cannot `push()` a value to it. To set a specific index to a specific value use `tArray[i] = value`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r thank you for this information !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create an array of your desired size, fill it with `"-"` and then at your specific location, set the number:

```js
const number = 2, maxSize = 4;

const tArray = new Array(maxSize).fill('-');
tArray[number] = number;

console.log(tArray);
```

Comment: as you can see the output the number is been pushed at index 3 not at index 2

Comment: @AmAnKumAr Lets count: 0, 1, 2, 3. No, I'm pretty sure it's at index 2. Also thanks for basically copying my answer lol.

Comment: No it is pushed at index 3 and after testing in my code worked very fine  in multiple case ! thank you @AmAnKumAr

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of pre-defined size and then put data inside the array

```js
let data = 4;
let size = 10; // as much as you like

let array = new Array(size).fill('-');

// now when the data comes from the web socket you can simply put inside the array

array[data - 1] = data;
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```js
const tArray = [];
if (tArray.length < number+1) {
  while (tArray.length < number+1) {
    tArray.push('-');
  }
}
tArray[number] = number;
```

Your code should be fine too if you change the `tArray[i].push()` part in `tArray.push()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the current array(`tArray`) with a [new Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with length equalse to:

Your Number (and position) - current [array length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) + 1

this has
to happend only if current array(`tArray`) is no big enough

```js
var tArray = [];
var pushIntoTarray = function (number) {
    if (tArray.length < number) {
        tArray = tArray.concat(new Array(number - tArray.length + 1).fill("-"));
    }
    tArray[number] = number;
    console.log(tArray);
}
pushIntoTarray(4);
pushIntoTarray(2);
pushIntoTarray(1);
pushIntoTarray(10);
```